# How to disable persistent bridge interfaces in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04

I see a bunch of bridge interfaces that come up on my ubuntu 18.04 machine. They look like `br-00a87e65d75d`. I can use `brctl delbr` to delete them, but they comeback after a reboot. I am not able to figure out what's causing them. Can someone point at what to look at? /etc/network/* has nothing in it pointing to the bridge interfaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Persistent bridges and interfaces are defined in /etc/network/interface. Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in my case all these bridges were created for docker networks. If you have docker installed that's probably the same for you too. To check, run `docker network ls` and compare the Network ID with the ID after br- in your bridge interfaces. If they are the same then they were created for docker.

To remove all unused networks run `docker network prune` and after reboot those bridges won't be created again.